Dell Vostro 3910 Volume too low
I just bought a new Dell Vostro 3910 and installed Ubuntu 22.04.5LTS 64 bit.  When I plugged in a pair of speakers in the back the volume is too low.  The headphones in the front jack are fine.  I already looked at the "Dell Vostro 14 5480 very low volume" post and it didn't look like it matched the configuration for the 3910.
I've included a screenshot of the Codecs that come up.
